# Capacitor with multiple pins

Tags: capacitor

I have a capacitor with 3 pins + 4 for assembly(common ground?).
It is paired and I found it in an old (tube/valve amplifier) TV.

I couldn't find any docs about it.

It has written on it:

---

Tesla TC 448

{circle} - 200uF 350V

{square} - 100uF 350V

{triangle} - 50uF 350V

---

What do these mean? How do I have to connect it to my circuit to reach the capacitance I want?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share a photograph of it?

Comment: @nidhin Here is a site where its sold: [has an image too](http://aukro.cz/kondenzator-tesla-tc-448-350v-200uf-2ks-i5222031554.html?bi_s=archiv_aukro&bi_m=page-user-items-page&bi_c=link-recommended-top-box)

Comment: Be wary of using old electrolytics, they have a nasty habit of breaking down. The resulting BANG may result in a sudden need for trouser replacement.

Comment: @Jimdearden Thanks for the tip, I'll just get some new ones then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a multi-section capacitor usually used in power supplies.  Yours has 3 sections with a common terminal. The circle, square and triangle symbols indicate each of the 3 sections.

Comment: Could you explain how would I get 50uF for example?
And am I correct to assume that the four other leads are the common terminal?

Comment: For 50 uF, triangle +ve, common -ve, ignore the others.